# How to get my Discord bot's creation date?

Tags: discord.js

I don't know how to get my Discord bot's creation date but I need it. Can someone tell me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client object gives you access to a class known as ClientUser ([see here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser)) and it allows you to access the **createdAt** property here ([see here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=createdAt))

Example:

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
        console.log(`[BOT] I'm ready! Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
        console.log(`Creation Date: ${client.user.createdAt}`);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know when your Bot was started:

```js
var creationDate = Date.now() - client.uptime
```

If you want to know when the actual files of your Bot were created, you can use `fs` for that.

```js
var fs = require('fs');
fs.stat('./path/to/file.js', (err, stat) => {
   if(err) throw(err);
   var creationDate = stat.birthtime; //NOTE: this is unavailable on Linux 
})
```

If you want to know when the Account your Bot is using was created:

```js
var creationDate = client.user.createdAt;
```